# Access ViewState from Static method in aspx page

Tags: asp.net

suppose i have one static method and i need to access viewstate from that method...how could i do so...i know it is not possible but there must be some way out.

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string GetData(int CustomerID)
 {
     string outputToReturn = "";
     ViewState["MyVal"]="Hello";
     return outputToReturn;
 }
```

Comment: If you know it's not possible, why do you think there must be a way to do so?

Comment: The `ViewState` of what? `ViewState` is part of a `Control/Page` - but you appear to be calling a (static?) `WebService`, so there is no `ViewState`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the reference to the page via [HttpContext.CurrentHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.currenthandler.aspx). But since [`Control.ViewState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate(v=vs.110).aspx) is protected **you can't access it** (without using reflection) as opposed to the `Session` which is accessible via `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

So either don't use a static method, use the `Session` or use this reflection approach:

```
public static string CustomerId
{
    get { return (string)GetCurrentPageViewState()["CustomerId"]; }
    set { GetCurrentPageViewState()["CustomerId"] = value; }
}

public static System.Web.UI.StateBag GetCurrentPageViewState()
{
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
    var viewStateProp = page?.GetType().GetProperty("ViewState",
        BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy |
        BindingFlags.Instance |
        BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    return (System.Web.UI.StateBag) viewStateProp?.GetValue(page);
}
```

However, this won't work if called via WebService, because then it's outside of [Page-Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

You might be able use `[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]` for your `PageMethod`, and use `Session` instead of `ViewState`. Remember, with a static `PageMethod` no instance of the Page class is ever created, so nice things like `ViewState` simply are not there and there is no way to make them be there.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this and worked for me:

- Create a class conteining the properties of the viewState you want to access to
- In the constructor pass the real ViewState
- Create a static instance of the class but not initialize it
- In the PageLoad initialize Not static class and the static one
- Access the ViewState using static class properties
- 

```
public class Repository
{
    public int a
    {
        get
        {
            if (_viewState["a"] == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return (int)_viewState["a"];
        }
        set
        {
            _viewState["a"] = value;
        }
    }

    public StateBag _viewState;

    public Repository(StateBag viewState)
    {
        _viewState = viewState;
    }
}

static Repository staticRepo;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repository repo = new Repository(ViewState);

    staticRepo = repo;
}

public static void testMethod()
{
    int b = staticRepo.a;
}
```